# The command '/bin/sh -c conda env create -f environment.yaml' returned a non-zero code: 137

Tags: docker, conda

Trying to run conda in dockerfile. Ran into "The command '/bin/sh -c conda env create -f environment.yaml' returned a non-zero code: 137
" on step 4"RUN conda env create -f environment.yaml".Also tried giving a bigger memory by"docker build --memory="16g" -t onepose_plus ." Does not work. Can anyone help me to fix it or provide a method to use docker instead of conda into docker? Down below is my dockerfile and environment.yaml,
dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /OnePose_Plus_Plus-main

# Create the environment:
COPY environment.yaml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yaml 

# Make RUN commands use the new environment:
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Demonstrate the environment is activated:
RUN echo "Make sure flask is installed:"
RUN python -c "import flask"

# The code to run when container is started:
COPY run.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "myenv", "python", "run.py"]
```

environment.yaml:

```
name: oneposeplus
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pytorch=1.8.0
  - torchvision=0.9.1
  - cudatoolkit=10.1
  - ipython
  - tqdm
  - matplotlib
  - pylint
  - conda-forge::jupyterlab
  - conda-forge::h5py=3.1.0
  - conda-forge::loguru=0.5.3
  - conda-forge::scipy
  - conda-forge::numba
  - conda-forge::ipdb
  - conda-forge::albumentations=0.5.1
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This portions suggests that pip would look for a requirements.txt.

```bash
  - pip:
    - -r requirements.txt
```

But if this is not available (your case) your commands would fail.

Just remove these lines if you do not need them or supply a file if you have one and retry.